# Android, FTP, File

Tags: android

Я пытаюсь создать файл и отправить на сервер. Мои ошибки:"No such file of directory" - хотя я так уже сохранял фото и "как мне правильно осуществить отправку данного файла"

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){

        FTPClient ftp = null;
        try {
            ftp = new FTPClient();
            ftp.connect("ftp.example.com", 21);
            ftp.login("user", "password");
            ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"MyDoc");

            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                File file_txt =  new File(directory,"text.txt");
                BufferedWriter in = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_txt));
                in.write("Text");
                in.close();
                //boolean result = ftp.storeFile("text.txt", in);
                in.close();
             } finally {
                 if (outputStream != null) {
                     outputStream.close();
                 }
             }       
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
         }
    }
}).start();
```

Хэлп!!!

Comment: По-моему, вам надо перестать копипастить код и начать разбираться, что каждая строчка делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь создать файл в папке, которая возможно не существует (`"MyDoc"`). Вам для начала нужно убедиться, что она существует, или создать ее. Для этого после

```
directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"MyDoc");
```

добавьте

```
directory.mkdirs();
```

Comment: как я понимаю, буфер же не закрыт и с помощью storeFile его можно загружать на серв, но там что-то не так......

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, вы вообще читали мой ответ? У вас ошибка, я написал, почему она возникает, и  дал решение. ЧТо вообще за буфер? Причем тут он?

Comment: так директорию и файл я создал(благодаря вам). И вот я открываю поток для чтения и хочу отправить на сервер:fis = new FileInputStream(Sourcefile);
                                boolean done = ftp.storeFile("text.txt", fis); Но дело в том, что создается пустой файл и при чтении происходит ошибка, а следственно и ошибка отправки.

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, задайте новый вопрос, если у вас возникла новая проблема. Не сваливайте все в кучу, иначе от вашего вопроса никакой пользы другим не будет.

Comment: вопрос закрыт - проблема решена!